# form validation does not work

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a question about my form. I think I made a mistake, it does not seem to be working. When I check a checkbox, not only that specific checkbox gets checked, all of the check boxes get checked.

```
<?php
session_start();
function quote_smart($value)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        if(version_compare(phpversion(),"4.3.0") == "-1") {
            return mysqli_escape_string($value);
        } else {
            return mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
        }
    }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_SESSION['captcha_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha_code'], $_POST['captcha_code']) != 0) {  
        $msg="<span style='color:red'>The Validation code does not match!</span>";  
    } else {    
        $msg="<span style='color:green'>The Validation code has been matched.</span>";  
        $servername = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        else {
            echo ("Connection good");
        }

        $fruit = array('berry', 'pear', 'apple', 'ananas', 'watermelon');
        $collection = array('berry', 'pear', 'apple', 'ananas', 'watermelon');
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $fruit = $_POST['champions'];
            $values = array();

            foreach($collection as $selection ) {
                if($selection === $fruit) {
                    $values[ $selection ] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    $values[ $selection ] = 0;
                }
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO fruit (student_name, student_email, berry, pear, apple, ananas, watermelon) {$values['berry']}, {$values['pear']}, {$values['apple']}, {$values['ananas']}, {$values['watermelon']},
           '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST["student_name"])."',
           '".$conn->real_escape_string($_POST["student_email"])."')";          

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            } 
        };
    }   
}   
?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear; your sample code does not show any checkboxes. Where is the part that check/unchecks checkboxes?

Comment: You should know which PHP version you are running. It would be abundant to check which version you are running; it's a waste of time and resources if you know it and it pollutes your code (in reaction of seeing you checking which PHP version you're using in your code).

Comment: On top of that, get_magic_quotes_gpc was removed from PHP since 5.somewhat, so when you know which PHP version you're running, you probably won't need to check if it's on or off. For as far as I can remember, having this functionality on was considered bad practice anyway.